# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when inflating a view from a jar

Tags: android, inflate-exception

I want to replace the rotating icon in progress dialog with my custom icon. The custom icon is part of my own jar placed inside /device//package_name/Custom_View.java. When this class is referenced in my frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/progress_dialog_holo.xml. I am having this crash

please  help me resolve this issue.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  699): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: WindowManagerPolicy
E/AndroidRuntime(  699): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.iamplus.aware.AwareProgressView
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:260)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at com.android.server.pm.ShutdownThread.beginShutdownSequence(ShutdownThread.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at com.android.server.pm.ShutdownThread.access$000(ShutdownThread.java:57)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at com.android.server.pm.ShutdownThread$1.onClick(ShutdownThread.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:190)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$PolicyThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:882)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iamplus.aware.AwareProgressView
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
E/AndroidRuntime(  699):    ... 15 more
```

Comment: yeah but why is it not able to pick the Custom View when it is part of  my jar.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848104/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-15-error-inflating-class

Comment: did u create the jar urself?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the external jar to your project build path.

After that, go to **Project ->  Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export** and mark the checkbox corresponding to your external jar.

Clean and build the project before you run.